# Recursive search Linq to xml

Tags: c#-4.0, twitter, linq-to-xml

this is my sample xml.

```
<Messages>
  <Conversation>
    <id>Z100</id>
    <ReplyToId></ReplyToId>
    <Message>Topic</Message>
  </Conversation>
  <Conversation>
    <id>A100</id>
    <ReplyToId></ReplyToId>
    <Message>This is a test</Message>
  </Conversation>
  <Conversation>
    <id>M100</id>
    <ReplyToId>A100</ReplyToId>
    <Message>What kind of test</Message>
  </Conversation>
  <Conversation>
    <id>A200</id>
    <ReplyToId>M100</ReplyToId>
    <Message>Stage 1</Message>
  </Conversation>
  <Conversation>
    <id>M200</id>
    <ReplyToId>A200</ReplyToId>
    <Message>Test result for </Message>
  </Conversation>
</Messages>
```

How to get the conversation list based on id using linq in C#. Say for example, If i want to get the conversation for id "A100" which has a link to other conversation based on ReplyToid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** *because of your clarification, I have re-written my answer.*

### Constructing the Conversation Tree

1. Use `XElement` to **load the root element** and its children from your xml file:

   ```
   var root = XElement.Load(@"path\to\your.xml"); 
   // Alternatively, XElement.Parse(stringContainingXML);
   ```
2. **Transform the elements** into conversations (the conversation class is given below):

   ```
   var conversations = (from element in root.Elements()
                        select Conversation.FromXElement(element)).ToList();
   // ToList prevents multiple iteration of the IEnumerable
   ```
3. **Add the replies** to each conversation:

   ```
   foreach (var conversation in conversations)
   {
       conversation.Replies.AddRange( 
       conversations.Where(reply => reply.ReplyToId == conversation.Id));
   }
   ```
4. *Optionally,* remove the replies from the top level:

   ```
   conversations.RemoveAll(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ReplyToId));
   ```
5. *Optionally,* to retrieve a single conversation by id:

   ```
   Conversation singleConversation = conversations.Single(x => x.Id == "A100");
   ```

---

### Result

```
Z100: Topic
A100: This is a test
*->M100: What kind of test
   *->A200: Stage 1
      *->M200: Test result for
```

---

### Conversation Helper Class

```
public class Conversation
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string ReplyToId { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public readonly List<Conversation> Replies = new List<Conversation>();

    public static Conversation FromXElement(XElement source)
    {
        return new Conversation
        {
            Id = (string)source.Element("id"),
            ReplyToId = (string)source.Element("ReplyToId"),
            Message = (string)source.Element("Message")
        };
    }     
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you look at the xml, the complete conversation list for id "A100" consist of 4 conversation. A100 -->M100 -->A200-->M200. Question is how to get the entire conversation based on a single id which is linked to other messages on ReplyToId. I tried your code , it returns a single conversation.

Comment: @RajEsh I updated my answer. Now, the entire conversation tree is constructed.

Comment: But i actually wanted to query specific conversation list based on a ID , in this case A100.

Comment: @RajEsh I thought that was so trivial that I left it out. I've added it as point 5.

Comment: Thank you so much :-).To let you know why i created this sample xml is for getting the conversation between two twitter screen names. In twitter terms, Statuses and interactions. I had spent so much time in doing research on it but could find none. There was not a single way to find the continuous conversation on a specific #topic. User timeline gives you a bunch of xml for both screen names. What i had framed here is the short form of it :-). Thanks once again. in the real scenario i'll be having two screen name xml objects. I can use AddRange to merge both and then use your technique.

Comment: using the fifth method will return a single object and not the entire tree conversation for A100 :-). Single object refers to one piece of message and excludes the replies for it. What i was looking for is when i pass "A100" it should get me all the related conversation of this ID.

Comment: no ;) actually, the fifth method returns a single object, but that object contains within its `Replies` another object (`M100`) and so on, all the way to `M200`. Thus, you have the whole conversation. But anyway, I'm glad my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had to include one more function to do recursive search :-).

```c#
public IEnumerable<Conversation> GetReplies() {
  yield return this;

  if (Replies != null) {
    foreach (var item in Replies
                          .Where(s => s != null)
                          .SelectMany(x => x.GetReplies())) {
      yield return item;
    }
  }
}
```